# JSF outputlabel clear

Tags: jsf, label, output

I have the following problem. I use a form when I provide only PIN. I have validator which checks if its a 4-digit number. Then the action on submit is set to the method which checks if the PIN exists in the database. If not it does message = "no PIN"; I used the message in the output label below the form. Previously it was null so there was no message there. Now it changes into "no PIN" but I have to clear it after clicking the submit button again because the error message doesn't disappear when you enter for example "12as" PIN and validator takes care of it. How should i implement such situation? Maybe using an output label in such situtation is a wrong idea?

Comment: please post your code (here too:)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use JSF message component outside a validator:
For a message for your input in your form:

```
 <h:message for="PIN"/>
```

And at your managed bean you can add a FacesMessage using:

```
FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,"No pin summary message","No pin detail message");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("PIN", message);
```

No need to use a outputLabel here.

Comment: I did what u said and it works but it doesn't appear in the message. It appear below in orange color instead. Maybe the reason is that I use the same message to the validator output?

Comment: You can put a new message for your submit button. Also the orange color probably comes from the FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, you can change the severity.

Answer (score 4):

You should not perform validation in action method. You should use a real validator.

Just implement the [`Validator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html) interface accordingly. E.g.

```
@FacesValidator("pinValidator")
public class PinValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        String pin = (String) value;

        if (pin == null || pin.isEmpty()) {
            return; // Let required="true" deal with it if necessary.
        }

        if (!pin.matches("\\d{4}")) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("PIN must be 4 digits"));
        }

        if (!somePinService.exists(pin)) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("PIN is unknown"));
        }    
    }

}
```

Use it as follows:

```
<h:outputLabel for="pin" value="PIN" />
<h:inputText id="pin" value="#{bean.pin}" validator="pinValidator" />
<h:message for="pin" />
```

The faces message of the validator exception will end up in the `<h:message>` associated with the component on which the validator is been fired.

If you're using ajax to submit the form, don't forget to make sure that the message is also taken into account on ajax render.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the JSF `<h:outputLabel>` generates a HTML `<label>` element which is intented to [label a form element](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/label/) (e.g. `<input>`, `<select>`, etc). It's absolutely not intented to show an arbitrary piece of text such as a validation message. I recommend to put JSF aside for now and start [learning basic HTML](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/). This way you will understand better which JSF components to pick to get the desired HTML output.

Comment: But there is a problem. My isCorrectPIN() method also get name of the user from database and write it to the bean. I can't write anything from the validator. I had another problem with my code and i posted the code in other topic. this is the link when u can see the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490740/jsf-validator-with-custom-method

Comment: I extend Connector class in the WaiterBean so i cant use the method in a static way. I also don't want to create to sql queries - one for name update and one for PIN verification

Comment: I used onclick method which reset the label but I am not sure if i should do it like this

Comment: Just do the business job in bean's action method. If validation fails, it isn't invoked anyway. If you continue this way and use Ozan's approach, you're simply performing a bad practice.